# Mongodb - How to delete sections of the database in discord.py?

Tags: python, mongodb, discord, discord.py, pymongo

I am currently working on something that deletes a users channel when they leave, this was working fine in my test server however now i've put it on the main server it is not functioning. The error I get is shown below: ( I am using diskord.py which is 99% identical to discord.py , only difference being wherever `discord` should be it says `diskord`)

```py
Ignoring exception in on_member_remove
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/diskord/client.py", line 428, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/container/cogs/shopside.py", line 157, in on_member_remove
    await channeldelete.delete()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'delete'
```

The intended result is it deletes the channel and the log of it in the database

The actual result is neither of these happen and in the logs shown below it says `NO` to the user having had a channel.

My code:

```py
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_remove(self, member):
        channelfind = cluster["Channels"]["shopside"]
        if member.guild.id == shopsideid:
            joinedat = diskord.utils.utcnow() - member.joined_at
            time = humanize.precisedelta(joinedat, format="%0.0f")
            embed = diskord.Embed(title="\u200b", color=0xfc8eac)
            embed: Embed = diskord.Embed(
                description= f'**{member.mention} left the server**\n:timer: **Joined:**\n{time} ago\n:question:**Shop Channel?**\n`NO`',
                color=0xfc8eac
            )
            embed.set_author(name=member, icon_url=member.avatar.url)
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar.url)
            embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
            embed.set_footer(text=f'ID: {member.id} \u200b ')
            memberid = channelfind.find_one({"member_id": member.id})
            if memberid is not None:
                channelid = memberid['channel_id']
                channeldelete = member.guild.get_channel(channelid)
                await channeldelete.delete()
                deletedata = { "member_id": member.id }
                x = channelfind.delete_many(deletedata)
                print(x.deleted_count, " documents deleted.")
                aembed = diskord.Embed(title="\u200b", color=0xfc8eac)
                aembed: Embed = diskord.Embed(
                    description= f'**{member.mention} left the server**\n:timer: **Joined:**\n{time} ago\n:question: **Shop Channel?**\n`YES.` Channel Name was: {channeldelete.name}',
                    color=0xfc8eac
                )
                aembed.set_author(name=member, icon_url=member.avatar.url)
                aembed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar.url)
                aembed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
                aembed.set_footer(text=f'ID: {member.id} \u200b ')
                log = shopsidelog
                await self.bot.get_channel(log).send(embed=aembed)
            else:
                log = shopsidelog
                await self.bot.get_channel(log).send(embed=embed)
                pass
```

Part of the code that the error also refers to:

```py
  @diskord.application.slash_command(description="Creates a shop channel", guild_ids=[shopsideid])
    @diskord.application.option("member", description="Who is this channel for")
    @diskord.application.option("name", description="Channel Name")
    @diskord.application.option("category", description="Use the category ID that you want the channel in")
    @diskord.application.option("description", description="If no channel description wanted type None")
    @diskord.application.option("nsfw", description="True or False")
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
    async def createchannel(self, ctx, member: diskord.Member, name: str = None, category: diskord.CategoryChannel = None, description: str = None, nsfw: bool = False):
        if description == None:
            description = " "
        category = category
        memberrole = ctx.guild.get_role(shopsidemember)
        moderator = ctx.guild.get_role(shopsidemod)
        channel = await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(name, category=category, )
        await channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, view_channel=False)
        await channel.set_permissions(moderator, view_channel=True, send_messages=True, manage_messages=True)
        # SET MOD AND ADMIN ROLE PERMS HERE
        await channel.set_permissions(memberrole, view_channel=True, send_messages=True)
        await channel.edit(topic=description)
        if nsfw == True:
            await channel.edit(nsfw=True)
        channelid = channel.id
        await ctx.send(f"Channel Created: <#{channelid}>")
        await channel.send(f"<@{member.id}> Welcome to your channel")
        channeldb = cluster["Channels"]["shopside"]  
        newchannel = {"member_id": member.id, "channel_id": channel.id}
        channeldb.insert_one(newchannel)
```

Any help is appreciated thank you in advance

Comment: Of what type is `memberid`? If it is a `dict`, does it have a key `channelid`? Is that a valid `int` Discord channel id in your guild?

Comment: Where is `get_channel` defined?  Apparently is can return None.